# Stop splitting words for non-English languages

Tags: input-methods, text-input

How can one stop Android's autocorrect from adding spaces to split compound words? This is terrible behaviour for many non-English languages.

Short story long: The default behaviour of the Android input method is English-centric even for non-English languages. A particularly infuriating feature is automatic splitting of compound words. In many North European languages including my own (Danish), compound nouns must not be separated, or the result will be either nonsense or a subtle change of meaning. It is bad that this is default behaviour for Danish, German, Swedish, and other non-English language input methods, but worse that it is not obvious how to switch it off. Is it possible?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

***No*, it is not a setting that you can toggle**; however, you can add the compound word to your dictionary (in [Google Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin), double-tap the word in the prediction bar), and in the future, it won't split up the words that you add.